# Changing permission of directory

Tags: permissions, filesystem

Change the permission of directory DIR1 such that users will be able to cd into DIR1 but
not be able to list the names of files and directories in DIR1.

It is a practice question for linux. I know that i can change permission with chmod with various ways, i usually use binary format but i dont know what to do here.

Comment: What research have you done on your own? The [Unix section of the wikipedia article on filesystem permissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File-system_permissions#Traditional_Unix_permissions) contains all the information required to answer this.

Comment: Hello. Sure it is not a homework question?

Comment: thats makes sense. i understand it thank you @vidarlo